# Javascript: How to check for certain items in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

How can I check if the items in an array like:

```
var dayPartsArr = ['PT','WDM','WDD','EF','WKE'];
```

are also the keys in an object like:

```
 var dayPartsMap = {
   'PT': 'PRIME TIME',
   'WDM': 'WEEKDAY MORNING',
   'WDD': 'WEEKDAY DAYTIME',
   'EF': 'EARLY FRINGE',
   'WKE': 'WEEKEND DAYTIME'
 };
```

Keep in mind the order of the `dayPartsArr` should not matter. So if

```
var dayPartsArr = ['WKE','PT','WDM','WDD','EF'];
```

I still want to be able to use `dayPartsMap` to check if each item in `dayPartsArr` is a key in `dayPartsMap`

Comment: Why not just use a proper Map?

Answer (score 2):

### Ignoring Order

Ignoring order, we can take the input array and compare it to the keys like so:

```
var dayPartsArr = ['WDM','PT','WDD','EF','WKE']; //out of order

var dayPartsMap = {
  'PT': 'PRIME TIME',
  'WDM': 'WEEKDAY MORNING',
  'WDD': 'WEEKDAY DAYTIME',
  'EF': 'EARLY FRINGE',
  'WKE': 'WEEKEND DAYTIME'
};

dayPartsArr.every(item => ~Object.keys(dayPartsMap).indexOf(item)); // true

// Compare against an array with a missing key
dayPartsArr = ['WDM','PT','FAKE', 'WDD','EF','WKE'];

dayPartsArr.every(item => ~Object.keys(dayPartsMap).indexOf(item)); // false
```

> Note the `~` is the [bitwise NOT operator](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_bitwise.asp), it helps with indexOf

### Previous Answer

You can convert the Object's keys to an array and compare that array, like so:

For more information on Object.keys, [check MDN here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```
var dayPartsArr = ['PT','WDM','WDD','EF','WKE'];

var dayPartsMap = {
  'PT': 'PRIME TIME',
  'WDM': 'WEEKDAY MORNING',
  'WDD': 'WEEKDAY DAYTIME',
  'EF': 'EARLY FRINGE',
  'WKE': 'WEEKEND DAYTIME'
};

// Create the comparison function...
function arraysIdentical(a, b) {
   var i = a.length;
   if (i != b.length) return false;
   while (i--) {
       if (a[i] !== b[i]) return false;
   }
       return true;
};

/// compare!
arraysIdentical(dayPartsArr, Object.keys(dayPartsMap)); // true
```

*`arraysIdentical` originally suggested by [Tim Down](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7837725/7103969)*

Comment: What about if the items in  dayPartsArr were in a different order? would this still work? See my revised question above

Comment: @NewToJS Note this also works if the `dayPartsArr` contains duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `every` and `filter` to solve the issue.

Ref:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

```js
var dayPartsArr = ['PT','WDM','WDD','EF','WKE'];
var dayPartsMap = {
   'PT': 'PRIME TIME',
   'WDM': 'WEEKDAY MORNING',
   'WDD': 'WEEKDAY DAYTIME',
   'EF': 'EARLY FRINGE',
   'WKE': 'WEEKEND DAYTIME', 
};

// > 1 for WKE
// var dayPartsArr = ['PT','WDM','WDD','EF','WKE', 'WKE'];

const check = Object.keys(dayPartsMap).every(key =>   dayPartsArr.filter(day => day === key).length === 1);

console.log(check);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.every` to check if all items of `dayPartsArr` are present in `dayPartsMap` keys:

```
var dayPartsArr = ['PT','WDM','WDD','EF','WKE'];

var dayPartsMap = { 'PT': 'PRIME TIME', 'WDM': 'WEEKDAY MORNING', 'WDD': 'WEEKDAY DAYTIME', 'EF': 'EARLY FRINGE', 'WKE': 'WEEKEND DAYTIME' };

var objKeys = Object.keys(dayPartsMap);
var result = dayPartsArr.every(day => objKeys.includes(day));

console.log(result);
```